# Run MySql query multiple times until specific value is found in one of 5 fields

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a table of subscribers. each subscriber row has fields w1, w2, w3, w4, w5.

```
row1    email | w1 | w2 | w3 | w4 | w5
row2    email | w1 | w2 | w3 | w4 | w5
row3    email | w1 | w2 | w3 | w4 | w5
```

the 'w' fields can have 0,1, or 2

I need to run a query checking the 'w' fields, if the field has a 2 rerun the query and check the next 'w'

example:

```
run the function for w1;
if w1 == 2
run the function for w2;
if w2 == 2
run the function for w3;
if w3 == 2
run the function for w4;
if w4 == 0 or == 1
set variable to true
OR if w4 == 2
run the function for w5
```

here is my current function:

```
function checkForComplete($nextwidgetNumber, $email) {

global $mysqli, $response;

$complete = false;

$nextwidget = 'w'.$nextwidgetNumber;

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ".$nextwidget." FROM subscribe WHERE emailaddr=? AND trash != 1 AND archive != 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);

    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($widget);

    $stmt->store_result();

    $stmt->fetch();

    // if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
    if($widget == '2')
        $complete = true;

    $response['status'] = "successful completed widget";
    $response['complete'] = $complete;

} else {
    $response['status'] = "query failed";
}

    $stmt->close();

    return $response;

}
```

this is the function call:

```
checkForComplete($nextwidgetNumber,$email);
```

Comment: Have you tried something? If so, please include it in your question by pressing the "Edit" button below the questions tags, Remember to include any errors that was generated by your attempt.

Comment: I have added the function. I need to call the function and if the result equals 2 increment the 'w' field by one and run the function again. continue this until the value equals 1 or 0 OR stop if all field's values are 2

Answer (score 0):

```
select @variable = 1
from your_table
where w2 = 2
and w3 = 2
and w4 in (0,1)
```